# Filling pandas DataFrame with values regenerated from a function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to fill my dataframe (some columns) with a value from a NumPy array. The challenge is that I would like to fill all the columns which have a certain pattern. For example: assume my table has the following columns with the column names:

```
column name1:my test , column name 2: test , column name3: drive ,column name4: car
```

So I would like to only fill my test, test with value from a NumPy array which I created. Is it possible to fill my test (completely) and then test (completely) and eventually, fill the other column with the column names which have a target string with "test"?

Comment: yes, why don't you try it

Comment: This what i am trying:  pk=pd.DataFrame(Built(), columns= list(DataFrameTable.filter(regex= re.compile("test", re.IGNORECASE))). where DataFrameTable is my DataFrame(empty) containing the columns name mentioned earlier. The function built () return a list  with 10 values. So i want to fill the columns with the pattern test in my DataFrame with 10 values from the built function. That is what i tried. Sorry but i really new to this. Thank you

Comment: Well have you tried `df['my test'] = some_data`?

Comment: just for one column name? yes i did and it work but; i would like to do it all the column with that target string. I want to do it automatically  i might not know how many columns and at which position are the columns with "test" in the dataframe.

Comment: you can do `df[col_list] = your_data` so long as the shape matches it should work, so try it

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".